# Is it possible to find an actual function source code by its object definition?

Tags: javascript

I'm using firefox, but can use Chrome, Opera and so forth as well. Since in our JavaScript code base we have too much lines and source files I'd like to have a facility to find the actual function declartion by its name in a debugger. What I meant was I wanted to set the breakpoint within the function, but simply don't know where it is.

For instance, when I click the button the following script is exetuing:

```
$('#name_btn').invoke();
```

I don't know where `invoke()` has been defined. Searching for the name of the function through the entire workspace (I'm using `Eclipse`) by `*.js`-file pattern didn't get any useful result as well.

Is it possible to find it in the debugger built in a browser?

Answer (score 1):

In the debugger, set a breakpoint on this line:

```
$('#name_btn').invoke();
```

Then, when it hits that breakpoint, step into the function.  This will go into the jQuery constructor. Step out of that function (this will bring you back to this same line).  Then, step in again.  This will take you to the `.invoke()` function and you can see where the source is coming from.

---

If the multiple steps are too complicated, you can simplify the debugger operations by changing the code to this:

```
 var obj = $('#name_btn');
 obj.invoke();
```

Set the breakpoint on the second line.  When it hits the breakpoint, step into the function and you will be in the `invoke()` method.

---

FYI, the Chrome debugger also has a search function that will search all the loaded JS files for any symbol you want to look for.

Comment: Well, this invokation is within onclick attribute.

Comment: @St.Antario - make the onclick attribute call your own function that you can more easily set a breakpoint in.

Answer (score 1):

Also in Chrome tools you can search the sources:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox and Chrome, you can just do this from the console:

```
debug($('#name_btn').invoke)
```

i.e. `debug(fn)` will set a breakpoint at function `fn` entry point. No need to hunt for the definition. (Unless you can't get the reference to the function, of course.)

EDIT: Confirmed for Chrome as well.

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome's Developer Console:

```
$('#name_btn').invoke
```

Or (assuming these are jquery functions in $.fn):

```
$.fn.invoke
```

Type the function without calling it and hit enter, and it will print the source of the function as it saw it as well as which file it read the definition from on the right hand side of the console.

http://i.imgur.com/YlBi8QA.png

Comment: Neat, but if it's minified, you can't really do much with it in the way of breakpoint setting. :(

Comment: I doubt most dev work is done with pre-minified files though :)